# How to validate mat selection list in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have written a code to show the list of products and it has the facility to select the products (using a checkbox). When I save it, I need to know what are the products they have selected. Please help.

**Code**

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-work-order-status',
    templateUrl: 'work-order-status.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['work-order-status.component.scss']
})

export class WorkOrderStatusComponent implements OnInit {
    statuslist: string[] = ['InRepair', 'Hold', 'Closed', 'Built', 'Shipped', 'WIP'];
    worderobj: any;
    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<WorkOrderStatusComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
            this.worderobj = [data];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    public onClose(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    public onSave() {
    }
}
```

**work-order-status.component.html**

```html
<mat-selection-list #status>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let list of statuslist">
        {{list}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutAlign="end end">
    Options selected: {{status.selectedOptions.selected.length}}
</div>

<div fxLayoutGap="8px">
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onSave()">Change</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First place value input property to mat-list-option component and bind the list value

**component.html**

```
<mat-selection-list #status>
    <mat-list-option [value]="list" *ngFor="let list of statuslist">
        {{list}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Then pass the template reference variable to onsave method

```
<div fxLayoutGap="8px">
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onSave(status)">Change</button>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

Then acces the selected value like this

```
onSave(status){
    const value = status.selectedOptions.selected.map(sel=>sel.value);
    console.log(value);
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeenft?file=app/list-selection-example.ts)